# Redux multiple dispatches asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm using Redux for my website and I have two dispatches I want to make when the page is loaded. The 2nd dispatch waits for the 1st dispatch (which makes an ajax call) to finish so that it can use the data from the 1st dispatch. The problem is right now the 2nd dispatch does not wait for the 1st dispatch to finish so this.props.allData is empty. How do I go about doing this? I've tried using redux-thunk and promises too but to no avail.

```
componentWillMount() {

    this.props.dispatch(fetchAllData())
    this.props.dispatch(fetchData(this.props.allData, this.props.params.id))

}
```

---

this would give me an error saying "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

```
getAllData() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return dispatch(fetchAllData()).then(()=> {
      dispatch(fetchData(this.props.allData, this.props.params.id))
    })
  }
}


componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(this.getAllData())
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried. `redux-thunk` can easily handle these use cases.

Comment: @StevenMercatante okay edited post

Answer (score 0):

You have too many calls to `dispatch` in `getAllData`. Try something like this:

```
getAllData() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return fetchAllData().then((resp)=> {
      dispatch(fetchData(resp.payload, this.props.params.id))
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm fetchAllData is an action that i'm importing from another file, it says it's undefined, sorry i'm relatively new to redux and redux-thunk

Comment: An `undefined` error isn't related to redux or redux-thunk; it's an issue someplace else that you'll need to fix first.